# child div not inheriting parent div height

Tags: css, html

I can't get a child to inherit the parent div's height automatically when I load it in chrome.  I created the below example and when I run it in jsfiddle it works some how (in chrome) but not when I run it from visual studio!!

The different is, in my project the outter tag is in a _layout page and the child content is in a RenderBody() call - not sure if that makes a difference?

```
.HtmlEditorBodyContainer {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
}

.NewsOutter {
    background-color: green;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}

.NewsInput {
    border: 5px solid red;
    /*width: 75%;
    height: 25%;*/
}

.NewsCreate {

}

.NewsSideBar {

}
```

_Layout page

```
<div class="HtmlEditorBodyContainer">
    @RenderBody()        
</div>
```

@RenderBody() content

```
<div class="NewsOutter">
        <img src="" id="image">
        <div class="NewsInput">

        </div>
        <div class="NewsCreate">

        </div>
        <div class="NewsSideBar">

        </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rzLo9cc0/

Comment: So it uses Internet Explorer then?

Comment: what uses Internet explorer?

Answer (score 0):

```
.NewsOutter {
    background-color: green;
    height: calc(100%);
    width: calc(100%);
}
```

perhaps this helps

Comment: thanks, I should have said I tried that also without any luck.  If I set a size like 500px it increased but it won't inherit.

Comment: @JQuery try using calc()